# Google Map V3 API Not working in localhost

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I copied following javascript code from google maps documentation, but it doesn't work, it only shows a white blank page, nothing loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
   <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Geolocation</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">

<!--
Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
See: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor
-->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
  }


  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
       }

         var options = {
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
         content: content
       };

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
       map.setCenter(options.position);
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Since v3 require api key what's wrong with it? I checked in google chrome and firefox but no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a closing `html` tag, unless that is a typo.

Add this `</html>` at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Sorry my mistake...when i cut and paste it omitted. no it is not the reason it not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `center` location to create your `map`. In your `initialize()` function change the map options to include the location you want to start with:

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(60.0,105.0);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 6,
  center: myCenter, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

When (or if) you get a location from the geolocation service the center will be changed by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, will answer anyhow in case anyone else lands here.

I ended up using a slightly different implementation to get this to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                                  mapOptions);
  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'+
                 '&key={{API_KEY}}&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript();
</script>
```

The part that I had to add to get it to work from other (nearly identical) versions of this, was the () at the end of loadScript(). The implicit function call simply was not happening.

You will need to replace {{API_KEY}} with your own. I am not sure if this is required, but it was part of what led me to a working implementation.

If you do not have one, follow the steps listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)